# need to remove first cell top border

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html-table, bootstrap-table

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center ">
  <thead class="">
    <tr>
      <td class="bg bg-white invisble border-0"></td>
      <th colspan="8">
        Attribute Name
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Prices</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value1</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value2</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value3</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">price category 1</th>
      <td>2500.00</td>
      <td>3400.00</td>
      <td>1500.50</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>7800.12</td>
      <td>1578.34</td>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">price category 2</th>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>7800.12</td>
      <td>1568.34</td>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>2500.00</td>
      <td>3400.00</td>
      <td>1500.50</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">price category 3</th>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>2500.00</td>
      <td>3400.00</td>
      <td>1500.50</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>7800.12</td>
      <td>1568.34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

red mark indicate what i need to remove

[image]

above attached image can see wrap from red line just I need to remove border. I just many of way. but I could not find a way to remove it. I just need to remove that . so output like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You know it is horrible idea to name table like you did.

Use `<caption>` element instead:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center ">
  
  <thead class="">
    <tr class="border-0">
      <th class="border-0"></th>
      <th class="border" colspan="8">Attr name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Prices</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value1</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value2</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value3</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Attribute Value4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
      <th>Cash</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">price category 1</th>
      <td>2500.00</td>
      <td>3400.00</td>
      <td>1500.50</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>7800.12</td>
      <td>1578.34</td>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">price category 2</th>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>7800.12</td>
      <td>1568.34</td>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>2500.00</td>
      <td>3400.00</td>
      <td>1500.50</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">price category 3</th>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>2500.00</td>
      <td>3400.00</td>
      <td>1500.50</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>1200.00</td>
      <td>7800.12</td>
      <td>1568.34</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @mplungjan No, but i edited it, check this out!

Comment: @abdulaziz0 hi need just like 2nd attached image.

Comment: @ChamiduPurage done, 2nd edit as you want)